# Export Excel rows as records to a SQL Server database so my tag data translates/fits properly to the many to many TEXTs&TAGs tbl?

Tags: sql-server, excel, etl, vba

My actual Excel has about 1,000 rows/records and up to 5 comma separated tags per record in a "TAGS" column. Very open to any and all suggested solutions besides manually populating the TEXTs&TAGs tbl.

The Excel & SQL Server resemble this:

**Excel:**

```
TEXT              TAGS
--------------------------------
1.derivatives     math, calculus
2.triangles       math, geometry
```

**Database:**

**TEXTs** tbl

```
1.derivatives
2.triangles
```

**TAGs** tbl

```
1.math
2.calculus
3.geometry
4.science
```

**TEXTs&TAGs** tbl (many to many)

```
1.1,1
2.1,2
3.2,1
4.2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADODB ([tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),  [another one](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx)) to connect to SQL Server from your VBA macro in Excel. Then just insert records one by one like this. It won't by very fast, but should be OK for your needs.

```
Sub update()
    For I = 1 To 100
        txt = Sheet1.Cells(I, 1)
        txt_id = insertAndGetIdForText(txt)

        tags = Split(Sheet1.Cells(I, 2), ",")

        For Each Tag In tags
            tag_id = getIdForTag(Tag) #insert if not in DB, otherwise just return id
            Call insertTextTag(txt_id, tag_id)
        Next Tag
    Next I
End Sub
```